# WPF mvvm backgroundWorker busyIndicator

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, backgroundworker, wpftoolkit

I'm using the [busyIndicator](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator&referringTitle=Documentation) in my program that works with MVVM pattern, I found out that there is a problem with background worker and dealing with objects that are binded in the view so I used the Dispacher.Invoke method on all of the functions that use binded properties, after I used the Dispacher the busyIndicator showed up, but when the backgoundWorker finished my view had no elements inside, what am I doing wrong?

I know it's a little low in code but i didn't know what (and if) will help, if necessary please let me know and I'll edit this message with the desired code.

**EDIT:**

Here is some code that might help:

This is the creation of the BW, it happens on the viewModel constructor

```
        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bw.RunWorkerAsync(false);
```

This is the BW functions

```
 void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsBusy = false;
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BusyContent = "Please Wait...";
        this.IsBusy = true;
        ShowSystem((bool)e.Argument);
    }
```

The method showSystem is very long so I'll add just the part that using UI elemnts

```
List<NodeViewModel> nodes = null;
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => nodes = new List<NodeViewModel>()));

int width = 0;
int height = 0;

foreach (var system in MainNet.Systems)
{
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => nodes.Add(CreateNode(system.Name, new Point(width, height), false, system.InputNum, system.OutputNum, system.Interfaces, system.Enums, system.Structs, update))));

    width += 150;
    if (width >= 700)
    {
        width = 0;
        height += 100;
    }
}

if (MainWindow.IsFlow)
{
    Object[] getInterfacesWithGuidToFlowParam = new Object[1];
    getInterfacesWithGuidToFlowParam[0] = MainWindow.GuidToFlow;

    interfacesForFlow = (List<String>)getInterfacesWithGuidToFlow.Invoke(sqlDB, getInterfacesWithGuidToFlowParam);

}

foreach (var system in MainNet.Systems)
{
    if (system.OutputNum > 0)       //this system has an output connector
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var outId in system.Outputs)       //loop throw all systems ids that current system is connected to 
        {;
            ConnectionViewModel connection = null;
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => connection = new ConnectionViewModel()));

            Object[] getSystemNameParams = new Object[1];
            getSystemNameParams[0] = outId;
            string destSystemName = "";

            destSystemName = (String)getSystemName.Invoke(sqlDB, getSystemNameParams);

            NodeViewModel sourceItem = null;
            NodeViewModel destItem = null;
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => sourceItem = nodes.Find(x => x.Name == system.Name)));

            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => destItem = nodes.Find(x => x.Name == destSystemName)));
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => destItem.InputSystems.Add(sourceItem.Name)));

            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => sourceItem.OutputSystems.Add(destItem.Name)));

            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => connection.SourceConnector = sourceItem.OutputConnectors[i++]));

            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => connection.DestConnector = destItem.InputConnectors[destItem.InputConnectors.Count - 1]));

            // Add the connection to the view-model.
            //
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => connection.Type = ConnectionViewModel.ConnectorType.REGULAR));
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => this.Network.Connections.Add(connection)));

            if (MainWindow.IsFlow)
            {
                foreach (var @interface in interfacesForFlow)
                {
                    String[] systems = @interface.Split('_');
                    if(systems[0].Equals(sourceItem.Name) && systems[1].Equals(destItem.Name))
                        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => connection.Type = ConnectionViewModel.ConnectorType.FLOW));

                }                                 

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

This is the part of getting the data from Database:

```
MainNet = Common.Model.Network.getNetwork();
        Debug.WriteLine("MainNet.Systems.Count = " + MainNet.Systems.Count);
        if (MainNet.Systems.Count == 0)
            update = true;
        List<String> systemNames = new List<string>();
        if (update)
        {
            if(MainNet.Systems.Count > 0)
                MainNet.Systems.Clear();
            if (this.Network.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                this.Network.Nodes.Clear();
                this.Network.Connections.Clear();
            }

            try
            {
                systemNames = (List<String>)getAllSystemMethod.Invoke(sqlDB, null);
                Debug.WriteLine("Success getAllSystemMethod");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.addMessage("Error in getAllSystemMethod: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                Debug.WriteLine("Error in getAllSystemMethod: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
            }

            #region CreateSystems
            foreach (var sysName in systemNames)
            {
                #region Intializating
                ObservableCollection<Common.Model.Enum> enums = new ObservableCollection<Common.Model.Enum>();
                ObservableCollection<Common.Model.Struct> structs = new ObservableCollection<Common.Model.Struct>();
                ObservableCollection<Common.Model.Interface> interfaces = new ObservableCollection<Common.Model.Interface>();
                //List<Model.Enum> enums = new List<Model.Enum>();
                //List<Model.Struct> structs = new List<Model.Struct>();
                //List<Model.Interface> interfaces = new List<Model.Interface>();

                int systemId = -1;
                Object[] getSystemIdParams = new Object[1];
                getSystemIdParams[0] = sysName;
                try
                {
                    systemId = (int)getSystemId.Invoke(sqlDB, getSystemIdParams);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Success getSystemId systemId = " + systemId);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.addMessage("Error in getSystemId: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error in getSystemId: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                }

                List<int> sysEnumsIds = new List<int>();
                List<int> sysStructsIds = new List<int>();
                List<int> sysInterfacesIds = new List<int>();

                Object[] getSysEnumsIdParams = new Object[1];
                getSysEnumsIdParams[0] = systemId;
                try
                {
                    sysEnumsIds = (List<int>)getSysEnumsId.Invoke(sqlDB, getSysEnumsIdParams);      //return List<int> all system Enums ids
                    if (sysEnumsIds.Count > 0)
                        Debug.WriteLine("Success getSysEnumsId first count is " + sysEnumsIds.Count);
                    else
                        Debug.WriteLine("success getSysEnumsId but no ids found");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.addMessage("Error in getSysEnumsId: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error in getSysEnumsId: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                }


                Object[] getSysStructsIdParams = new Object[1];
                getSysStructsIdParams[0] = systemId;
                try
                {
                    sysStructsIds = (List<int>)getSysStructsId.Invoke(sqlDB, getSysStructsIdParams);
                    if (sysStructsIds.Count > 0)
                        Debug.WriteLine("success getSysStructsId count = " + sysStructsIds.Count);
                    else
                        Debug.WriteLine("success getSysStructsId but no ids found");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.addMessage("Error in getSysStructsId: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error in getSysStructsId: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                }


                Object[] getSysInterfacesIdParams = new Object[1];
                getSysInterfacesIdParams[0] = systemId;
                try
                {
                    sysInterfacesIds = (List<int>)getSysInterfacesId.Invoke(sqlDB, getSysInterfacesIdParams);
                    if (sysInterfacesIds.Count > 0)
                        Debug.WriteLine("Success getSysInterfacesId count = " + sysInterfacesIds.Count);
                    else
                        Debug.WriteLine("success getSysInterfacesId but no ids found");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.addMessage("Error in getSysInterfacesId: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error in getSysInterfacesId: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
                #endregion

                    Object[] getStructFromIdParam = new Object[1];
                    getStructFromIdParam[0] = @struct;
                    List<Object> tempStruct = new List<object>();
                    try
                    {

                        tempStruct = (List<Object>)getStructFromId.Invoke(sqlDB, getStructFromIdParam);

                        Debug.WriteLine("Success getStructFromId " + tempStruct.Count);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        logger.addMessage("Error in getStructFromIdParam : " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error in getStructFromIdParam : " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                    }
                    structs.Add(new Common.Model.Struct(Convert.ToString(tempStruct[0]), Convert.ToString(tempStruct[1]), Convert.ToString(tempStruct[2]), fields, bitFields));
                    Debug.WriteLine("Success adding new struct: " + structs.Last().Name);






                }
                #endregion

                #region GetInterfaces
                foreach (var @interface in sysInterfacesIds)        //get interface
                {

                    ObservableCollection<Common.Model.Message> messages = new ObservableCollection<Common.Model.Message>();
                    ObservableCollection<Common.Model.Definition> definitions = new ObservableCollection<Common.Model.Definition>();
                    ObservableCollection<Common.Model.Include> includes = new ObservableCollection<Common.Model.Include>();

                    List<int> includesIds = new List<int>();
                    List<int> definitionsIds = new List<int>();
                    List<int> messagesIds = new List<int>();


                    #region getIncludes
                    Object[] getIncludesIdsParams = new object[1];
                    getIncludesIdsParams[0] = @interface;
                    try
                    {
                        includesIds = (List<int>)getIncludesIds.Invoke(sqlDB, getIncludesIdsParams);
                        Debug.WriteLine("Success getIncludesIds " + includesIds.Count);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        logger.addMessage("Error in getIncludesIds: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error in getIncludesIds: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                    }

                    foreach (var id in includesIds)
                    {
                        Object[] getIncludeParams = new object[1];
                        getIncludeParams[0] = id;
                        string includeName = "";
                        try
                        {
                            includeName = (string)getInclude.Invoke(sqlDB, getIncludeParams);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Success get include name = " + includeName);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            logger.addMessage("Error in getInclude " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Error in getInclude " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                        }
                        includes.Add(new Common.Model.Include(includeName));
                    }
                    #endregion

                    #region getdefinitions
                    Object[] getdefinitionsIdsParams = new object[1];
                    getdefinitionsIdsParams[0] = @interface;
                    try
                    {
                        definitionsIds = (List<int>)getDefinitionsIds.Invoke(sqlDB, getdefinitionsIdsParams);
                        Debug.WriteLine("Success getDefinitionsIds " + definitionsIds.Count);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        logger.addMessage("Error in getDefinitionsIds: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error in getDefinitionsIds: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                    }

                    foreach (var id in definitionsIds)
                    {
                        List<Object> definition = new List<object>();

                        Object[] getDefinitionParams = new object[1];
                        getDefinitionParams[0] = id;
                        string includeName = "";
                        try
                        {
                            definition = (List<Object>)getDefinition.Invoke(sqlDB, getDefinitionParams);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Success getDefinisions " + definition[0]);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            logger.addMessage("Error in getInclude " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Error in getInclude " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                        }

                        definitions.Add(new Common.Model.Definition(Convert.ToString(definition[0]), Convert.ToInt32(definition[1])));

                    }
                    #endregion

                    #region getMessages
                    Object[] getMessagesIdsParams = new object[1];
                    getMessagesIdsParams[0] = @interface;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Trying to get messages for interface #" + @interface);
                    try
                    {
                        messagesIds = (List<int>)getMessagesIds.Invoke(sqlDB, getMessagesIdsParams);
                        Debug.WriteLine("Success getMessagesIds " + messagesIds.Count);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        logger.addMessage("Error in getMessagesIds: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error in getMessagesIds: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                    }

                    foreach (var id in messagesIds)
                    {
                        //List<Model.MType> types = new List<Model.MType>();
                        ObservableCollection<Common.Model.MType> types = new ObservableCollection<Common.Model.MType>();
                        List<int> typesIds = new List<int>();

                        Object[] getMessageTypesIdsParams = new Object[1];
                        getMessageTypesIdsParams[0] = id;
                        try
                        {
                            typesIds = (List<int>)getMessageTypesIds.Invoke(sqlDB, getMessageTypesIdsParams);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Success getMessageTypesIds " + typesIds.Count);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            logger.addMessage("Error in getMessageTypesIds: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Error in getMessageTypesIds: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                        }
                        foreach (var typeId in typesIds)
                        {
                            List<Object> type = new List<object>();

                            Object[] getTypeParams = new object[1];
                            getTypeParams[0] = typeId;
                            //string includeName = "";
                            try
                            {
                                type = (List<Object>)getType.Invoke(sqlDB, getTypeParams);
                                Debug.WriteLine("Success getType");
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                logger.addMessage("Error in getType " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                                Debug.WriteLine("Error in getType " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                            }

                            types.Add(new Common.Model.MType((string)type[0], (string)type[1], (string)type[2], (string)type[3], (string)type[4], (string)type[5], (Guid)type[6]));
                            Debug.WriteLine("Success adding new type: " + (string)type[0] + " " + (string)type[1] + " " + (string)type[2] + " " + (string)type[3] + " " + (string)type[4] + " " + (string)type[5] + " " + (Guid)type[6]);
                        }

                        string sourceSystem = "";
                        string destSystem = "";


                        List<Object> message = new List<object>();
                        Object[] getMessageParams = new Object[1];
                        getMessageParams[0] = id;
                        try
                        {
                            message = (List<Object>)getMessage.Invoke(sqlDB, getMessageParams);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Success getMessageParams");

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            logger.addMessage("Error in getMessageTypesIds: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Error in getMessageTypesIds: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                        }

                        messages.Add(new Common.Model.Message(types, message[0].ToString(), (int)message[1], message[2].ToString(), message[3].ToString(), message[4].ToString(), message[5].ToString(), message[6].ToString(), message[7].ToString(), message[8].ToString(), message[9].ToString()));
                        Debug.WriteLine("Success adding new Message: " + message[0].ToString() + " " + (int)message[1] + " " + message[2].ToString() + " " + message[3].ToString() + " " + message[4].ToString() + " " + message[5].ToString() + " " + message[6].ToString() + " " + message[7].ToString() + " " + message[8].ToString() + " " + message[9].ToString());

                    }
                    #endregion


                    Object[] getInterfaceFromIdParam = new Object[1];
                    getInterfaceFromIdParam[0] = @interface;
                    List<Object> tempInterface = new List<object>();
                    try
                    {

                        tempInterface = (List<Object>)getInterfaceFromId.Invoke(sqlDB, getInterfaceFromIdParam);

                        Debug.WriteLine("Success getInterfaceFromId " + tempInterface.Count);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        logger.addMessage("Error in getInterfaceFromId : " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error in getInterfaceFromId : " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                    }
                    interfaces.Add(new Common.Model.Interface(messages, definitions, includes, Convert.ToString(tempInterface[0]), Convert.ToString(tempInterface[1]), Convert.ToInt32(tempInterface[2]), Convert.ToInt32(tempInterface[3]), Convert.ToBoolean(tempInterface[4])));
                    Debug.WriteLine("Success adding new interface: " + interfaces.Last().Name);

                }

                #endregion

                #region InputOutputNumber
                List<int> inputs = new List<int>();
                List<int> outputs = new List<int>();

                int inputCount = 0;
                int outputCount = 0;

                Object[] getSysInputNumParams = new Object[1];
                getSysInputNumParams[0] = systemId;
                try
                {
                    inputs = (List<int>)getSysInputs.Invoke(sqlDB, getSysInputNumParams);
                    if (inputs != null)
                    {
                        inputCount = inputs.Count;
                        Debug.WriteLine("Success getSysInputNum inputs = " + inputCount);
                    }
                    else
                        Debug.WriteLine("Success getSysInputNum inputs = 0");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.addMessage("Error in getSysInputNum: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error in getSysInputNum: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                }


                Object[] getSysOutputNumParams = new Object[1];
                getSysOutputNumParams[0] = systemId;
                try
                {
                    outputs = (List<int>)getSysOutputs.Invoke(sqlDB, getSysOutputNumParams);
                    if (outputs != null)
                    {
                        outputCount = outputs.Count;
                        Debug.WriteLine("Success getSysOutputNum outputs = " + outputCount);
                    }
                    else
                        Debug.WriteLine("Success getSysOutputNum outputs = 0");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.addMessage("Error in getSysOutputNum: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error in getSysOutputNum: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
                #endregion

                Common.Model.System system = null;
                try
                {
                    system = new Common.Model.System(interfaces, enums, structs, sysName, inputCount, outputCount, inputs, outputs);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Success adding new system");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.addMessage("Error in creating new system: " + ex.Message);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error in creating new system: " + ex.Message);
                }
                MainNet.Systems.Add(system);
                Debug.WriteLine("Done! you now have a new system with: " + interfaces.Count + " interfaces And " + enums.Count + " Enums and " + structs.Count + " Structs, The name is: " + sysName + " numOfInput: " + inputCount + " numOfOutput: " + outputCount);
            #endregion


            }
        #endregion
```

Comment: Show us some of your code

Comment: The point is that there is a lot of code, what part will help?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "my view has no elements inside". Can you show us an example of how you are using `Dispatcher.Invoke` in your code, and what your expected result is vs what your actual result is?

Comment: @Rachel I updated my message with all my code, the expected result is a window with rectangles in it, the actual result is just a window without the rectangles, the BusyIndicator appears and the time of his appearance is consistent with the time i had to wait before i had the indicator

Comment: Was that code helpful?

Comment: @Yogevnn A bit... I'm still a bit unclear about how this is bound to the UI. The first things that come to mind is regarding the BackgroundWorker, you need to set `IsBusy` before kicking it off with `.RunWorkerAsync`. Setting `IsBusy` inside the worker means it won't be read by the UI until after the worker thread is completed. Second though is I see you're creating a `List<NodeViewModel>`, however where is that being used or bound to the UI? Or if this is not the property that you say isn't being updated in the UI, then which property is and where is it being set and updated at?

Comment: @Rachel i updated my AddNodesToUi region in the message, I added a dispacher code for the List<NodeViewModel> after that by running in debug the code stoped on a line 'destItem = nodes.Find(x => x.Name == destSystemName)' so i added it also via 'Dispacher' now same thing, it runs as if it is ok but nothing happens when it is done

Comment: Now I saw that my code says the the list 'nodes' is null this happens here: 'Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => nodes = new List<NodeViewModel>()));'  and then i'm checking ' if (nodes == null)
                        Debug.WriteLine("nodes=null");'

Answer (score 1):

The dispatcher is being used incorrectly here

The Dispatcher can be used to marshal code onto the UI thread, at a specified priority if desired. The code does not get executed and return immediately, but instead gets run at the priority specified according to the [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) order.

Basically your code is saying

- Create a List
- >> Queue code to populate the list on the UI thread at a later time
- If list is not null, execute some code

The list will always be null because the code to populate it hasn't been run yet. Its only been queued to run once when available.

The correct way to do this would be to populate your data on the background worker, and then marshal the results back onto the UI thread to populate your UI.

Note that objects can only be modified on the thread at which they were created on. So if you have some objects you plan on using and/or modifying from the UI later on, you should see something like this:

- Create objects
- Start BackgroundWorker to get data
- BackgroundWorker obtains data on background thread without locking up UI
- BackgroundWorker finishes and uses Dispatcher to run code on the UI thread that will update objects created at the first step with results

Comment: I'm not quit sure that I fully understand how sould I use the Dispatcher as you suggested because I have many classes and some other projects that should get this nodes List, so how can I use it in a way that will ensure that all other will be able to modify the list.
And what is your solution for my null problem? is there any wait for dispatcher method or somthing like that?

Comment: @Yogevnn Create your list on the main UI thread. Launch the background worker to get a list of objects to populate that list. At the end of the background worker thread, use the Dispatcher to assign the data obtained from the backgroundworker code to the list created on the main UI thread. Also, if you bind the UI to the List of objects and are modifying that list at runtime, you probably want to use an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of a `List<T>` so the UI receives notifications to update when the collection changes.

Comment: Thank you I'll check that and updated after if it worked

Comment: Ok so I did that and now the list is not null, my problem in the view is still there, i don't see the binded objects: 
NodesSource="{Binding Network.Nodes}"
                            ConnectionsSource="{Binding Path=Network.Connections}"

The Network is declered in my class as a property and I initialized it as you said, from the debug window (I have lots of debuging) i see that all the data is inside the Network but for some reason the view is not sowing them, what am i missing here?

Comment: I think it has something to do with what you said here: 
BackgroundWorker finishes and uses Dispatcher to run code on the UI thread that will update objects created at the first step with results.
Can you give me an example on how to do that because I don't think that i understand correctly

Comment: @Yogevnn Does the `Network` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and is the `Nodes` and `Connections` properties of type `ObservableCollection<T>` and not `List<T>`?

Comment: This is the connections ans nodes in the Network class:

public ImpObservableCollection<NodeViewModel> Nodes
        {
            get
            {
                if (nodes == null)
                {
                    nodes = new ImpObservableCollection<NodeViewModel>();
                }

                return nodes;
            }
        }
The connection is the same, i don't have enough space here

Comment: @Yogevnn Can you show your code that you are using to bind to the UI? My first thought is perhaps you have the wrong `DataContext` set. Also, do you get any binding errors when you start your application?

Comment: Yes! there are lot's of binding exceptions!

I'll edit my code with the binding expression of the nodes and connections

Comment: Well it's short so I'll add it here:


                            NodesSource="{Binding Network.Nodes}"
                            ConnectionsSource="{Binding Path=Network.Connections}"

Comment: @Yogevnn I'm assuming this is XAML. What is the `DataContext` of the object that contains the `NodesSource` and `ConnectionsSource` properties?

Comment: The NetworkViewModel, I added the class in the question, you can see there the `private ImpObservableCollection<NodeViewModel> nodes` and also the connections

Comment: @Yogevnn If the `DataContext` is your `NetworkViewModel`, then you should be binding to `Nodes` and `Connections`, like this: `<SomeItem DataContext="{Binding Network}" NodesSource="{Binding Nodes}" ConnectionsSource="{Binding Connections}" />`. The way you have it written now you are trying to bind to `NetworkViewModel.Network.Nodes`, which doesn't exist. (If you're new to WPF and strugging to understand how the `DataContext` works, you may be interested in reading a post I have on my blog for beginners: [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/))

Comment: Yes I'm very new to WPF and this is my BS.c final project which is due to next week, and this is the last think needs to be done I would really appriciate if you will help me to pass the reading and write me how should i modify this code: 

`NodesSource="{Binding Network.Nodes}"
                            ConnectionsSource="{Binding Path=Network.Connections}"`

Comment: @Yogevnn If you're working with WPF, I'd strongly suggest you read up on what the `DataContext` is and be sure you understand it :)

Comment: Thank you I will read it, but I really need to finish this thing as fast as possible :\ maybe you help me modify this two lines?

Comment: @Yogevnn I already told you the problem and the code to fix it. Your `DataContext` is set to your NetworkViewModel object, so you are trying to bind to `Network.Network.Nodes`, which doesn't exist. Change your bindings so it correctly binds to `Network.Nodes`.

Comment: I really appreciate your answers, but I'm not fully understanding how I should modify the binding. What should I write instead of what there is now?

Comment: I think my problem is that i don't understand why the `Network.Nodes` does not exist

Comment: @Yogevnn You have a `NetworkViewModel` called Network. You have it assigned to the `DataContext`. And you are trying to bind to `Network.Nodes`. That means the property WPF tries to obtain for the value is `DataContext.Network.Nodes`, however since DataContext is your NetworkViewModel, it means you are trying to access `Network.Network.Nodes`. Change your bindings like I said a few comments ago so it correctly binds to `DataContext.Nodes`, which will be `NetworkViewModel.Nodes`.

Comment: Ohhhh I'm so sorry! I was wrong! my dataContext is the mainWindowViewModel, there I have the ShowSystem method and all the data that need to be binded. I'm so sorry for the confusion, so if this is not my problem, why can't I see no nodes or connections when the BW stops? (It worked fine before I added the BackgroundWorker)

Comment: @Yogevnn Its very hard to tell what's wrong without seeing your code. You could either edit this answer with a reduced version of your code causing the problem, or ask a new one that details what you're attempting, what you've tried, and your expected result vs actual result. Also, I'd recommend [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) for debugging binding errors. That may tell you of any binding problems :)

Comment: I edited my messages, now you can see how i'm getting the data from the DB, Just to remind, the program worked perfect before the busyIndicator, now i'm seeing the indicator, the data is received from database without any exceptions, there are no null exception, but when the indicator disappear there is no UI elements on the UI, as if it needs to be refreshed