# C# backgroundWorker wait ReportProgress

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

Is there any way to "wait" for the `ReportProgress` method to end?

I'm updating a list on the `ReportProgress` method that after i'm calling to the method i'm using that list, which is wrong unless the `ReportProgress` has finished.

```
#region addNodesToUi

             //Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => ));
                nodes = new List<NodeViewModel>();

            try
            {
                //Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => ));

                Debug.WriteLine("Success creating new nodeViewModel");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.addMessage("Error in creating new nodeViewModel " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                Debug.WriteLine("Error in creating new nodeViewModel " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
            int width = 0;
            int height = 0;
            int i = 0;
            ObservableCollection<Common.Model.System> allSystems = new ObservableCollection<Common.Model.System>();
            lock (mainNetLocker)
            {
                allSystems = MainNet.Systems;
            }

            foreach (var system in allSystems.ToList())
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("inside Foreach in system: " + system.Name + " interface " + system.Interfaces.Count + " structs " + system.Structs.Count);
                if (nodes == null)
                    Debug.WriteLine("FUUUCCKKKK!");
                try
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Before add node");
                    try
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("trying to add: " + system.Name + " " + system.InputNum + " " + system.OutputNum + " " + system.Interfaces.Count + " " + system.Enums.Count + " " + system.Structs.Count);
                        //Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => nodes.Add(CreateNode(system.Name, new Point(width, height), false, system.InputNum, system.OutputNum, system.Interfaces, system.Enums, system.Structs, update))));
                        nodes.Add(CreateNode(system.Name, new Point(width, height), false, system.InputNum, system.OutputNum, system.Interfaces, system.Enums, system.Structs, update));
                        //bw.ReportProgress(i++, tempn

                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        logger.addMessage("Error adding new node to list " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error adding new node to list " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                    }
                    Debug.WriteLine("Success adding new node to list");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.addMessage("Error in adding new node to list " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error in adding new node to list " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
                width += 150;
                if (width >= 700)
                {
                    width = 0;
                    height += 100;
                }
            }

            if (MainWindow.IsFlow)
            {
                Object[] getInterfacesWithGuidToFlowParam = new Object[1];
                getInterfacesWithGuidToFlowParam[0] = MainWindow.GuidToFlow;

                    try
                    {
                        interfacesForFlow = (List<String>)getInterfacesWithGuidToFlow.Invoke(sqlDB, getInterfacesWithGuidToFlowParam);

                        Debug.WriteLine("Success getInterfacesWithGuidToFlow " + interfacesForFlow.Count);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        logger.addMessage("Error in getInterfacesWithGuidToFlow : " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error in getInterfacesWithGuidToFlow : " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                    }

            }

            foreach (var system in allSystems.ToList())
            {
                if (system.OutputNum > 0)       //this system has an output connector
                {
                    //int i = 0;
                    foreach (var outId in system.Outputs)       //loop throw all systems ids that current system is connected to 
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("out id = " + outId);
                        ConnectionViewModel connection = null;
                        try
                        {
                            //Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => connection = new ConnectionViewModel()));
                            connection = new ConnectionViewModel();

                            Debug.Write("Success creating new ConnectionViewModel");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            logger.addMessage("Error in creating new ConnectionViewModel " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Error in creating new ConnectionViewModel " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                        }
                        Object[] getSystemNameParams = new Object[1];
                        getSystemNameParams[0] = outId;
                        string destSystemName = "";
                        try
                        {
                            destSystemName = (String)getSystemName.Invoke(sqlDB, getSystemNameParams);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            logger.addMessage("Error in getSystemName: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Error in getSystemName: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                        }

                        NodeViewModel sourceItem = null;
                        NodeViewModel destItem = null;
                        //Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => sourceItem = nodes.Find(x => x.Name == system.Name)));
                        lock (networkLocker)
                        {
                            sourceItem = nodes.Find(x => x.Name == system.Name);
                        }

                        //int sourceId = nodes.FindIndex(sourceItem);
                        Debug.Write("Success creating new sourceItem");
                        //Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => destItem = nodes.Find(x => x.Name == destSystemName)));
                        lock (networkLocker)
                        {
                            destItem = nodes.Find(x => x.Name == destSystemName);
                        }

                        Debug.Write("Success creating new destItem");
                        try
                        {
                            //Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => destItem.InputSystems.Add(sourceItem.Name)));
                            destItem.InputSystems.Add(sourceItem.Name);

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            logger.addMessage("Error adding input system: " + ex.Message);
                            Debug.Write("Error adding input system: " + ex.Message);
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            //Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => sourceItem.OutputSystems.Add(destItem.Name)));
                            sourceItem.OutputSystems.Add(destItem.Name);

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            logger.addMessage("Error adding OutputSystems: " + ex.Message);
                            Debug.Write("Error adding OutputSystems: " + ex.Message);
                        }
                        Debug.Write("Success bah");
                        //int destId = nodes.FindIndex(destItem);


                        //Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => connection.SourceConnector = sourceItem.OutputConnectors[i++]));
                        connection.SourceConnector = sourceItem.OutputConnectors[i++];

                        Debug.Write("Success bah");
                        //Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => connection.DestConnector = destItem.InputConnectors[destItem.InputConnectors.Count - 1]));
                        connection.DestConnector = destItem.InputConnectors[destItem.InputConnectors.Count - 1];


                        Debug.Write("Success bah");

                        // Add the connection to the view-model.
                        //
                        //Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => connection.Type = ConnectionViewModel.ConnectorType.REGULAR));
                        connection.Type = ConnectionViewModel.ConnectorType.REGULAR;

                        //Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => this.Network.Connections.Add(connection)));


                        //Debug.Write("Success bah");
                        if (MainWindow.IsFlow)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("inside IsFlow!");

                            foreach (var @interface in interfacesForFlow)
                            {
                                String[] systems = @interface.Split('_');
                                Debug.WriteLine("Flow from: " + systems[0] + " To " + systems[1]);
                                if (systems[0].Equals(sourceItem.Name) && systems[1].Equals(destItem.Name))
                                    connection.Type = ConnectionViewModel.ConnectorType.FLOW;
                                    //Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => connection.Type = ConnectionViewModel.ConnectorType.FLOW));

                            }                                 

                        }
                        lock (networkLocker)
                        {
                            bw.ReportProgress(2, connection);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => ww.Close()));

                //bw2.ReportProgress(100);
            }
            #endregio
```

Well i couldn't upload the whole method, this is the part that addes the nodes to thee UI, the Updated from Database can be seen here: [Look at the edit below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504176/wpf-mvvm-backgroundworker-busyindicator)

Comment: Can you share some code? Why not call it on the WorkCompleted? Are you trying to wait until the DoWork is completely finished?

Comment: the DoWork is calling a function `ShowSystem` from that function i have binded UI elements that i'm updating throw the `ReportProgress` after i'm updating the elements (lists) i need to keep doing actions on them (in the same method- `ShowSystem`) and i figured out that i need to wait for the `ReportProgress` to end so that the list will contain all elements

Comment: @Miguel, the code for this question is in the predecessor question over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548685/wpf-mvvm-backgroundworker-ui-displaying-different-results  hope that helps

Comment: `catch (Exception ex) { Debug.Writeline(ex...); }` is usually a bad mistake as this will discard important diagnostic information then continue as if nothing has gone wrong. E.g. if `nodes.Add` fails in your code, you catch it then try to use `nodes`; that is going to give you false information. `catch` is for fixing errors, and `Debug` statements do not fix errors. Learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to serialize access to your ReportProgress method *AND* the worker method cannot be changed, you can change ReportProgress to this...

```
    private readonly Semaphore _throttle = new Semaphore(1,1);
    void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _throttle.WaitOne();
            if (e.ProgressPercentage == 1)       //update nodes
            {
                this.Network.Nodes.Add((NodeViewModel)e.UserState);
            }
            else if (e.ProgressPercentage == 2)       //update connections
            {
                this.Network.Connections.Add((ConnectionViewModel)e.UserState);
            }
            else if (e.ProgressPercentage == 3)
            {
                this.Network.Connections.Clear();
                this.Network.Nodes.Clear();
            }
            else if (e.ProgressPercentage == 4)
            {
                MainNet.Systems.Add((Common.Model.System)e.UserState);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _throttle.Release();
        }
    }
```

This approach adds a throttle to the callback that will force callers to wait until the ReportProgress has finished.  Only one caller can enter the body of the method at a time which is what you want to achieve.  The drawback is that the queue will block the UI, but that outcome is IMPLICIT in your question anyway.

The [Semaphore docs are here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx)

Comment: WOW this looks just like what i was looking!! i'm checking that immediately, thank you so much for your help!!!!

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not working :\ i'm so desperate right now, but i have a lead, all the UI looks great if i update from DB but when i'm pressing the show button again i don't need to update from data base so i'm just showing the model classes i already have, and then for some reason the UI is not rendered correctly, I'll edit this message with all the `showSystem` method maybe you will see something i don't

Comment: I updated my message with the addNodesToUI part and there is a link to where the getFromDB part is (sorry for linking, its too long for one message).

Comment: Ok so i have an update, the UI problem was something else, completly stupid, but when i'm running on debug mode i can see that the nodes list contains only 3 elements while its supposed to be filled in a foreach loop on all 4 elements i got from database this is the line: `destItem = nodes.Find(x => x.Name == destSystemName);`

Comment: Another thing i just found out, every run of the program there is a different outcome, sometimes a node is missing sometimes a list inside the node is missing, sometimes there are no node and sometimes it work perfectly...I'm guessing it's something to do with the threading....Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Ohh..Test driven? no i don't

Comment: It doesn't matter what i do, every time `showSystem` is called i'm getting a different outcome..sometimes good and sometimes bad

Comment: I'm in the c# chat room